# Java "<=" operator doenst give output, but "<" does. What is the issue?

Tags: java, while-loop, operators

I'm working on a while loop in Java, but the `<=` operator isn't following the conditions, but the `<` condition works fine. I don't understand what's the issue here.

```java
int m = 0;
int ssum = 0;

while (ssum <= 10) 
{
    m++;
    ssum = ssum + m;
    System.out.println(m + "  " + ssum + "\n" );
}
```

Output for m and ssum with the `<=` operator: (it should end when ssum is 10, but it goes on till 15)

[image: output for m and ssum with <= operator]

Output for m and ssum with `<` operator:

[image: output for m and ssum with < operator]

Comment: You check `ssum` is less than 10, *then* you add `m` to it and print it. It's not the same value when you print it as when you checked it.

Answer (score 0):

the value of 'ssum' is 10 when the while loop if condition is evaluated, which then gets changed to 15 inside the loop and printed as 15.

Comment: why doesn't the same happen with the "<" operator?

Comment: because 'ssum' is not less than 10 (its equal to 10) - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html